# cannot convert object 'list' to str implicitly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

I have been making a program for me to study math problems. Noe everything works perfectly up to a point. The problem is displaying the problem. I made it so that based off the level you choose it uses certain numbers. I will give code related to the problem:

```
Lvlonenumbers =list(range(1, 51))
if Level == 'Lvl.1':
    NumberList = Lvlonenumbers
NumberOne =random.choice(NumberList)
NumberTwo =random.choice(NumberList)
Answer =NumberOne + NumberTwo
print(str(NumberOne) + '+' + str(NumberTwo) + '=' + variable)
```

When the program goes to execute the print function it says cannot convert object 'list' to str implicitly. I do not understand why this happens. I have not seen this type of error before.

Comment: Post the full traceback. Is `variable` a list as well? It probably is.

Comment: I think you mean `+ '=' + Answer` as you don't have a `variable` name, and if you do, its probably a list.

Comment: Variable is a list of strings. all the letters of the alphabet separated.

Comment: You can't add a list to a string, because Python doesn't know how to convert a list to string. This is your basic problem. You can covert it beforehand by using a join, like this: `''.join(variable)`

Answer (score 0):

> Variable is a list of strings. all the letters of the alphabet
>   separated.

You can't add a list to a string, because Python doesn't know how to convert a list to string. This is your basic problem. You can covert it beforehand by using a join, like this: `''.join(variable)`:

```
lvl_one_numbers = list(range(1, 51))

if level == 'Lvl.1':
    number_list = lvl_one_numbers

number_one = random.choice(lvl_one_numbers)
number_two = random.choice(lvl_one_numbers)

print('{0}+{1}={2}'.format(number_one, number_two, ''.join(variable))
```

I also changed your variable names as per the [python style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).